# Gitlab CI/CD deploy to Azure Web Service

Tags: azure, continuous-integration, gitlab

I use GitLab for my CI/CD but I'm stuck at the deployment phase. Is there a way to use GitLab in order to deploy to azure web service? On the internet I can't find many examples, I only found one, but that solution seems a bit hacky.

Comment: What are you deploying? how are you deploying without gitlab?

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://blog.brooksjc.com/2018/12/27/gitlab-continuous-ci-cd-with-an-azure-web-app/) blog post has detailed explanation of GitLab CI/CD with an Azure Web App.